# create EditText without using XML

Tags: android, android-widget

In android app development wanted to create a EditText from java code without using XML,
So i wrote this

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String initMess="Hello Arun";
        private static final int VISIBLE = 0;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editText.setText(initMess.toString());
            editText.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

But while running the app in emulator EditText was not visible.

How to create an EditText using java only ?

Comment: you should add container such as ReleativeLayout in your xml. then add edit text into it.

Comment: please check: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(ll);

EditText et = new EditText(this);

et.setText("weeeeeeeeeee~!");

ll.addView(et);


this.setContentView(sv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set `Height` and `Width` parameters of the `EditText` like this.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

editText.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add Editext to your parent layout available in mainlayout.
let us assume you have relativelayout in your main

```
 layout.addView(editText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
//first set the layout 
LinearLayout linerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

// add edit text
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setText( "" );

// add editText to the view 
linerLayout.addView(editText);
```

Answer (score -1):

**firstly,you should get root view by layout file.**

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

**secondly,you should declare your child component like EditText**

```
EditText et =new EditText(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
et.setLayoutParam(p);
et.setText("text");
```

**thirdly,you should insert your child component into parent layout**

```
layout.addView(et);
```